# Как подключиться к базе firebird из android

Tags: android, android-studio, firebird

На локалхост размещена база. Как с этой базой работать из андроид?

Answer (score 1):

В андроид студио New Module -> Import Jar/Arr... -> файл Jaybird_2_2_12.aar (взял с оф сайта).

MainActivity

```
package com.example.jaroslavh.myapplication;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.StrictMode;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.util.Properties;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);

    try {
        Test2();
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, "Успішно", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        toast.show();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        toast.show();
    }

}

public void Test2() throws Exception {

    Class.forName("org.firebirdsql.jdbc.FBDriver");

    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.setProperty("user", "SYSDBA");
    props.setProperty("password", "masterkey");
    props.setProperty("encoding", "UTF8");

    Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(
            "jdbc:firebirdsql:192.168.0.96/3050:C:/IBExpert/db/TEST1.FDB",
            props);
   }
}
```

в файл build.gradle (файл относиться к Jaybird_2_2_12)

```
configurations.maybeCreate("default")
artifacts.add("default", file('Jaybird_2_2_12.aar'))
```

в файл build.gradle (файл относиться к модуль-апп)

```
dependencies {
.................
compile project(':Jaybird_2_2_12')
}
```

в файл firebird.conf (найти в папке C:\Program Files\Firebird\Firebird_3_0)

```
WireCrypt = Disabled
AuthServer = Legacy_Auth, Srp, Win_Sspi
AuthClient = Legacy_Auth, Srp, Win_Sspi
```

Ну и для полного комплекта, как для новичка, последующая выборка

```
   Statement statement = null;
        String query = " SELECT * FROM users";

        statement = connection.createStatement();
        ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery(query);

        while (resultSet.next()) {
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, resultSet.getString("id"),Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            toast.show();
        }
```